# How do I load pushed record updates using Ember-Data without conflicting with an inFlight transaction?

Tags: websocket, ember.js, ember-data

My Ember/Ember-Data/Rails application pushes data down to the client using WebSockets. I'm adding the pushed data to the store using Ember-Data's loadMany method.

However, if any of the pushed records are currently being edited and saved, loadMany will fail because the record is currently in the inFlight state. e.g.:

-> User edits record and clicks save
-> Ember-Data begins committing the current transaction
-> Rails controller responds with updated JSON for this record and publishes the updated data via WebSockets
-> WebSockets data is received before the transaction is completed, and Ember-Data attempts to update the record with this new data before the record is marked as clean

The only solution I've found is to defer applying the updates using Ember.run.later with a timeout of about 20ms. (Ember.run.next did not work.)

However, this only handles the situation where the user just saved the record. If, by coincidence, a record that the user is currently editing is edited by someone else and the push update is received before the transaction is completed, then the conflict would still occur and trigger an error.

So my question is, is there some way of either:

(a) Preventing the store from attempting to load changes when the affected record is inFlight;  or
(b) Delaying the push updates until all transactions are clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*crickets*`

For now, I've resolved this by manually checking if the record is in an un-updatable state and if it is, registering a callback for when it exits that state. Then after the callback I check  to see if the push update has a more recent `updatedAt` value than the record, and if it does, merge the two.